# Disambiguate Protocol Composition

Tags: swift, protocols, composition

is it possible to determine if a composed `Any.Type` contains a specific `Any.Type`?

`(A & B).self` contains `A.self` => true

`(B & C).self` contains `A.self` => false

**Code Example**

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}
typealias AB = A & B

func conformsToA(_ type: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    return type == A.self
}

print(conformsToA(A.self))       // true
print(conformsToA(AB.self))      // false (but should be true)
```

i could add a specific clause for `type == (A & B).self` inside of `conformsToA(_:)`, but this quickly becomes unmanageable. imagine if protocols C-Z are introduced and i tried to check something like:

```
conformsToA((A & C & E & Z).self)
```

**Another Attempt Using Alistra's 2nd Approach**

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}
typealias AB = A & B
func conformsToA<T>(_ t1: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return T.self is A
}

print(conformsToA(A.self))       // false (but should be true)
print(conformsToA(AB.self))      // false (but should be true)
```

Comment: I don't *believe* this is possible without creating instances of concrete types that conform to the given protocols – due to the fact that [protocols don't conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/2976878), therefore `AB.self` is not a `A.Protocol`. Although I'm curious what your use case for this is?

Comment: Interestingly, just found a curious bug while playing around with this – `A.self is A.Type` evaluates to `true` (it really shouldn't). The cast `A.self as! A.Type` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: as @Hamish said in the comment this is impossible.

There was a swift evolution proposal here that would fix it
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/91725ee83fa34c81942a634dcdfa9d2441fbd853/proposals/0126-refactor-metatypes-repurpose-t-dot-self-and-mirror.md#known-issues-of-metatypes

It didn't get into Swift 4 Stage 2.

You can use generics and `is`

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}
protocol C {}
typealias AB = A & B
typealias ABC = A & B & C

func conformsTo<T>(_ object: Any, t: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object.self is T
}

class CL : AB {}

print(conformsTo(CL(), t: A.self)) // true
print(conformsTo(CL(), t: AB.self)) // true
print(conformsTo(CL(), t: ABC.self)) // false
```

Or without instances of classes

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}
protocol C {}
typealias AB = A & B
typealias ABC = A & B & C

func conformsTo<T, U>(_ t1: T.Type, t2: U.Type) -> Bool {
    return T.self is U.Type
}


print(conformsTo(ABC.self, t2: A.self)) // false
print(conformsTo(ABC.self, t2: AB.self)) // false
print(conformsTo(ABC.self, t2: ABC.self)) // true
print(conformsTo(AB.self, t2: A.self)) // false
print(conformsTo(AB.self, t2: AB.self)) // true
print(conformsTo(AB.self, t2: ABC.self)) // false
print(conformsTo(A.self, t2: A.self)) // true
print(conformsTo(A.self, t2: AB.self)) // false
print(conformsTo(A.self, t2: ABC.self)) // false
```

Comment: Your second example is only matching the same cases, i.e `ABC.self` and `ABC.self` – but not cases like `ABC.self` and `A.self`.

Comment: unfortunately i need a solution without concrete objects, so the first option doesn't quite solve it. the second solution as pointed out by Hamish isn't quite what i am looking for either.

Comment: i have updated my code w/ a modified version of your second solution, but the results still aren't quite right